# Custom Android Menu from an ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, menu

I want my Android app to be able to show something like menu button would, but the menu would pop out from an imageview.

[image: this is an image. please upgrade your browser past DOS]

Comment: so where is the problem? attack onclicklistener to imageview and there show dialog ? you can try with context menu instead of dialog

Comment: Can't you just create this little menu (in the red "square") and animate it to show up?

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do. However to display the popup menu you can use PopupWindow http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PopupWindow:

Activity Class:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ImageView mOptionsImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mOptionsImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mOptionsImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mButton, 0, v.getHeight());

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // SOME YOUR CODE
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and popupWindow layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView> </LinearLayout>
```

Plese note: you will see no result, until your list is empty, add some buttons, textviews, or fill list with items before test this code.;)

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imV); // if declared in XML
imV.setOnClickListener(imVListener);

View.OnClickListener imVListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
//you can use QuickAction menu to pop up
}
};
```

And the [link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) to QuickAction menu.